# Programmatically compute UICollectionViewCell sizes from AutoLayout constraints made in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, storyboard, uicollectionview

The goal is to programmatically compute cell sizes for a UICollectionView based on constraints made in Storyboard inside of a UICollectionViewCell.

In other words, the sizes for elements of a UICollectionViewCell are defined inside of Storyboard using AutoLayout constraints.

But how do you gain access to those constraints in order to programmatically implement `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`?

The alternative is to hard code the values inside the view controller, but then you're defining sizes twice: once in Storyboard and once in code.

Is it possible to define the sizes once inside of Storyboard then let the view controller compute the cell sizes based on those constraints?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question as `UICollectionView` does use self-sizing cells with Autolayout. Once you've defined the constraints for your objects in your `UICollectionViewCell` subclass in the Storyboard the size of the cell is calculated automatically. You should not need to implement `collectionView:collectionViewLayout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` with correct constraints. What is the exact problem you are having with autolayout? Have you tried using the View Debugger?

Comment: @RoboticCat Thanks for commenting. The problem is the UICollectionViewCell is defined statically in the UICollectionView Size Inspector. So whatever value is there seems to override the self-sizing behavior, meaning if the cell size height is 50 in Size Inspector, the cell size height will be 50 no matter the AutoLayout constraints.

Comment: @RoboticCat Put another way, how do override the cell size values in the UICollectionView Size Inspector?

Comment: From memory, once you have setup the cell with autolayout you set the `estimatedItemSize` and it should just work. Of course, the constraints must work and some objects (like `UIImageView` or `UILabel`) may require extra constraints to "fix" their sizes. So the answer to your question is: Yes - it is possible.

Comment: @RoboticCat okay cool, will try this and if it works please post as an answer!

Comment: If it doesn't work then you will need to add more information about your collection view cell subclass and all the constraints in it.

Comment: @RoboticCat could you please post as an answer? Not working yet, but will keep trying. So far, tried this: `collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: CollectionViewTopPadding, left: 0, bottom: CollectionViewBottomPadding, right: 0)
        let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = collectionView.frame.size.` But it generates this error `the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values.`

Comment: I'm not sure it's worth an answer as it hasn't solved your question. Also, I was expecting you to set the `estimatedItemSize` on the `UICollectionView` rather than the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. Does this make a difference?

Comment: Tried to at first, but there doesn't seem to be an `estimatedItemSize` for `UICollectionView` (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/)? If it works for you, that means it should work, so please feel free to post an answer.

Comment: @RoboticCat hi any more suggestions on this?

Comment: @RoboticCat I am tired of banging my head with auto layout. It always gives me warning height and position are ambiguous, even after updating all constraints correctly.